# How does Spring Security/OAuth figure out the AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring project that uses spring-oauth2 and spring-security for authentication using an LDAP auth provider.

In controllers I can access the current principal's `UserDetails` using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation.

However, when I hit the endpoint with a client_credential token the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is a `String` which is the OAuth client id.  I understand that there's no notion of user when you authenticate with client_credentials, but I would like to have my Principal be a richer datatype. How does spring decide to set my principal as a `String` and can I override that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Oauth2 specs

> The client credentials (or other forms of client authentication) can
>      be used as an authorization grant when the authorization scope is
>      limited to the protected resources under the control of the client,
>      or to protected resources previously arranged with the authorization
>      server.  Client credentials are used as an authorization grant
>      typically when the client is acting on its own behalf (the client is
>      also the resource owner) or is requesting access to protected
>      resources based on an authorization previously arranged with the
>      authorization server.

because client can also be a resource owner, therefore spring will create authentication based on your client information.

I assume that you have setup `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` which is used to create authentication for the client.

You can create your own custom `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` or create your own `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider` to override how the authentication object is created, but I prefer to use `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer` to add additional information to the token generated.